# bootable usb stick

Tags: live-usb

can someone tell me any other way to make a bootable USB stick because my "Make Startup Disk" is not working,  it is not loading the image after selecting the image from the usb-creator-gtk window. I have a image of ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 2):

This method is very simple (it uses "dd" command) but please be **WARNED** that your USB stick existing content will be totally lost and you'll need to re-partition/re-format the stick afterwards for other purpose (file related) usage.

You should know the correct values for the following place-holders in the command below:

- [/full/path/to/image.iso] is the full path to the Ubuntu 13.04 image;
- [usb_device] is the name of your USB stick device (sdX - X being a, b, c - you should know it). Please make sure you **CORRECTLY** identify the USB stick device because otherwise you'll **WIPE another disk**.

Command:

```
sudo dd if=[/full/path/to/image.iso] of=/dev/[usb_device] bs=1M
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try UNetbootin .

UNetbootin allows you to create bootable Live USB drives for Ubuntu 13.04. It runs on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X.

You can download it [here](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) .

Answer (score 0):

You could use live-CD of multisystem (currently it is like - in about Ubuntu 12.10) too - burn multisystem*.iso on to a CD/DVD with drag and drop e.g. in k3b or simply 
with wodim in terminal (download is here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/multisystem/ ) :

> wodim -v -eject ms*.iso

With multisystem you can place several distributions on to one usb-stick.